# Semantic UI transitions on Hover

Tags: jquery, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to get a semantic UI app to do transition modules on hover.  I have them working on document ready.

I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xkrx/33/

but I'll put my code here too.

JS

```
$(document)
  .ready(function() {

//this works
      $('.fade-down')
      .transition('bounce')
    ;
//this doesn't
      var self = this;
      $('.fade-down').hover( function() {
      self.transition("bounce");
      })
  })
;
```

HTML

```
    <div class="fade-down column">
      <div class="ui icon header">
        <i class="circular code link icon"></i>
        Graphic Design 
      </div>
      <p>Yada yada</p>
      <p><a class="ui red right labeled icon button" href="#">Websites<i class="right long arrow icon"></i></a></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fade-down').hover(function(){
        $(this).transition('bounce');
    }, function(){});
});
```